# Scala Akka | How to use the allButSelf property inside an Cluster?

Tags: scala, akka

Based on the Akka documentation for Cluster, would I like to Publish a Broad message to all nodes in the Cluster **except** **myself**. Currently it's always sending the Broad message to me as well.

```
val mediator = DistributedPubSub(context.system).mediator
mediator ! Subscribe("content", self)       // subscribe to the topic named "content"
mediator ! Publish("content", "msg")        // sends the msg out Broad to all nodes including myself
```

**How exactly can I set the documentation property "allButSelf"?**

https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/current/distributed-pub-sub.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to do

```scala
mediator ! DistributedPubSubMediator.Put(testActor)
mediator ! DistributedPubSubMediator.SendToAll(path, msg, allButSelf=false) // it is false by default
```

See the example here https://github.com/akka/akka/blob/0e4d41ad33dbeb00b598cb75b4d29899371bdc8c/akka-cluster-tools/src/test/scala/akka/cluster/pubsub/DistributedPubSubMediatorRouterSpec.scala#L56